# Unknown MySQL server host 'loclhost' (-2) in popsql

Tags: popsql

when i try to create table, the running fails showing error   "Unknown MySQL server host 'loclhost' (-2)"  and in the schema trouble shooting error

Answer (score 0):

Had the same exact issue. For some reason, re-tytping "localhost" in the connection settings for mysql in popsql and then setting connection type to "Connect directly from my computer" worked for me. Can't explain why, bbut it works